# MYSQL FULL JOIN simulation query, unexpected result

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, markers and markerDetails.  I want to append to the rows of markers values from rows of markerDetails, NULL VALUES IF THERE ISN'T A ROW IN markerDetails.  The common columns on both are latitude and longitude.  I've tried many different variations of `UNION` with `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`.

Here's my query right now, simple and it almost works:

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM markers as m LEFT JOIN markerDetails as md 
        on m.latitude=md.latitude AND m.longitude=md.longitude WHERE m.whoAdded='$user'");

//tried, same result as above
mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM markers as m LEFT JOIN markerDetails as md on
    m.latitude=md.latitude AND m.longitude=md.longitude WHERE m.whoAdded='$user' UNION SELECT * FROM markers as m 
    RIGHT JOIN markerDetails as md on m.latitude=md.latitude AND m.longitude=md.longitude");
```

Problem with this query, if there isn't a row in markerDetails, for some reason it gives me a NULL id, NULL latitude and NULL longitude.  If there is a row in markerDetails, I get the id of markerDetails row, not the markers row...

Ideally I want to have the entire row from markers with appended row from markerDetails, with one instance of latitude and longitude...and still using `WHERE m.whoAdded='$user'`.  What am I not understanding with JOIN queries here?

```
markers STRUCTURE:
id  latitude  longitude  whoAdded  locationType  locationName  numChecks numImgs numRevs   timeadded
markerDetails STRUCTURE:
id  latitude  longitude  locAdd  locHrs  locPh  locSt  locApp  locMsg  locMn
```

So the desired output should be:

```
id (of markers), latitude, longitude, whoAdded, locationType, locationName, 
numChecks, numImgs, numRevs, locAdd, locHrs, locPh, locSt, locApp, locMsg, locMn
```

Comment: Can you provide a list of columns you're bringing back in the two queries? By using "select *" you're bringing back all columns of the two tables on both sides, so the output will certainly look awkward. Your bottom query should select the same columns but from the side opposite of the top.

Comment: @BrianDeMilia I added the structure of my two databases.  Instead of doing `SELECT *`, should I write out exactly which columns I want from both columns?

Comment: Thanks, what are the output columns that you want in your select list? As to your question, yes, but you also have to specify from which table you want the column to come from, which will be different for your top query vs your bottom query. This is why you're seeing nulls in places you don't want nulls.

Comment: @BrianDeMilia I added the desired output.  It seems weird that from the first query it seems that the main table used is the markerDetails.  If there isn't a row, it sets the id, latitude and longitude to NULL

Comment: try the sql in my answer below, if it's not what you expect can you add a few rows of sample data from each table and your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT m.id,
       m.latitude,
       m.longitude,
       m.whoAdded,
       m.locationType,
       m.locationName,
       m.numChecks,
       m.numImgs,
       m.numRevs,
       md.locAdd,
       md.locHrs,
       md.locPh,
       md.locSt,
       md.locApp,
       md.locMsg,
       md.locMn
  FROM markers as m
  LEFT JOIN markerDetails as md
    on m.latitude = md.latitude
   AND m.longitude = md.longitude
 WHERE m.whoAdded = '$user'
```

Comment: Thanks, for the most part it works.  UNION ALL returns the result twice for some reason so I'll stick with UNION.  Only strange thing is if there is no row in markerDetails, the WHERE statement doesn't seem to work...I get all the data...could it be the cause of non existing row in markerDetails?

Comment: Actually...it isn't about the empty row...I added another WHERE statement in the second part of the query and not it works exactly how it should...getting only the markers rows of the user

Comment: union all won't eliminate duplicates whereas union does (basically it adds DISTINCT to the query) so that would make sense if for some reason there are duplicates, might have to do with the join. When you say the WHERE clause doesn't work, are you talking about the top part of the query or the bottom part of the query? The bottom part of the query currently brings back ALL rows from markrdetails where there is no match on markers. You only have a WHERE clause on the top query, not the bottom query.

Comment: How do you want to filter (in the bottom query) rows of markerdetails where there is no match with markers? The "whoadded" column is only on markers, so you can't filter markerdetails in the same fashion.

Comment: @denikov try putting the criteria for "m.whoAdded = '$user'" into the on clause rather than the where clause as you put in the edit. The difference is that all rows of markerdetails where there is no match with markers will still come back, and for where there is a match, rows where that user matches the variable will be targeted.

Comment: @denikov in other words if you were to put that criteria into the WHERE clause of the bottom query, you'd be turning the right outer join into an inner join, which I don't think you want. On the bottom that criteria should probably go in the ON clause if I understand your problem correctly.

Comment: Well adding the WHERE clause to the bottom query gives me exactly what I need.  Changing the bottom WHERE to include it in the ON clause gives me the user's markers PLUS all the other data with a NULL whoAdded.  The only way it works exactly how I need it is having two WHERE clauses...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60777/discussion-between-brian-demilia-and-denikov).

Comment: @denikov what happens when you run just the top query, without the bottom part connected with the union? I think the result would be the same as if you run the union query with the bottom part having such a WHERE clause.

Comment: You're right...just having the top part of the query returns the same correct results that I wanted without having to UNION

Comment: @denikov I just updated the answer with the top only then. The reason is because when you put a condition in the where clause on an outer joined table it turns the outer join into an inner join. In other words you use an outer join to allow one of the tables to have nulls (no match), but in the WHERE clause you were saying that user ID had to be 'X' (whatever the var is). In order for it to have been X, it couldn't be null (there had to be a match with markers).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do INNER JOIN the two tables.

```
mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM markers m, markerDetails md where 
    m.latitude=md.latitude AND m.longitude=md.longitude AND m.whoAdded='$user'");
```

Further you can restrict the columns you need in the above select query.

Comment: That doesn't work because if there isn't a row in markerDetails, the return is empty, doesn't even give me the markers row.  Also, it is still giving me the id of markerDetails row instead of markers row id

Comment: If you want rows from markers even if you don't have a matching row in markerDetails then your original LEFT JOIN would work.